# Does the order in which variables are declared makes a difference?

Tags: c, variables, time, limit

I was solving a very simple question(to calculate square root) on codechef but when I run the code it shows time limit exceeded. I then looked at one of the submitted solutions and found that the only difference between the two codes was the order in which variables were declared.

Here is the code which works

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
    int ans,n,t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        ans=sqrt(n);
        printf("%d\n",ans);
    }
}
```

And here is my code which doesn't work

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
    int t,n,ans;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        ans=sqrt(n);
        printf("%d\n",ans);
    }
}
```

The only difference being the order in which variables are declared.

Comment: No, it makes no difference.

Comment: If it would, I'd be surprised by any TLE detector to have their treshold in between.

Comment: Are you sure you copied and pasted both codes as they are?

Comment: Check the time taken for execution, using `time  ./executable`

Comment: What do you mean with *does not work*? It crashes, simply exits or give unexpected results? And in that last case what does it give?

Comment: Yes I'm sure @Yksisarvinen

Comment: The code gives the expected output, just takes more time than the problem specified(the problem says timit limit is 1 second, while according to the compiler my code takes 5 second). @SergeBallesta

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula According to the compiler, my code takes 5 seconds to execute. That's what I can't understand, why such a simple code takes so long to execute while it works perfectly fine on codeblocks. And why only changing the the order in which variables are declared makes everything fine.

Comment: If `t` happens to be a negative number, the while loop basicly never stops. The proper condition is `t-- > 0`

Comment: 't' refers to number of test cases so it is positive(given in the question). @koder

Answer (score 0):

> Does the order in which variables are declared makes a difference?

No, the order in which variables are declared does not affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not specified, how order of declaration is translated into register or stack offsets. Therefore it depends on the compiler, if the order makes a difference. You could compare the assembly output for the difference. But with scanf and printf in between you should not see any relevant timing difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the overwhelming majority of cases, order of declaration will have little or no effect on program execution time.

It is **possible** that order of declaration can have a significant effect on program execution time, as when a change of order happens to result in changes such as what is spilled to the stack while executing a function, which cache line happens to be used at a particular time, or other effects that are normally small but that can cascade to produce larger effects. Such cascades are quite rare and are often neglected in design unless they manifest. When discovered, they are usually resolved not be rearranging the declarations but by considered redesign of the algorithm to avoid the cascade.

The program you show is too small and simple for this to happen in normal systems. The few items it needs in the `main` routine fit handily in processor registers, and there would be no significant effects from changing which registers are used for them.

Note also that compilers commonly do not use the order of declaration as the order of assignment of memory or registers to variables. Many compilers read and interpret the source code in a sort of holistic way, constructing an abstract representation of the work it does, and then generates code to implement that representation, not to slavishly follow the original source code. Because of that abstract representation, declaring the variables in a different order might not affect the generated code at all. The memory assigned to variables might depend more on their types and names than on their order of declaration. Nonetheless, it is still possible that the order of declaration can have some effect, simply because of incidental effects on how the compiler builds its database of identifiers used in the source code.